# Convert wordpress.com website to android app

Tags: android, json, wordpress, web

How do I query a wordpress.com site for information to build the android app. I am new to this. Wordpress.org suggests using JSON but that is not available on wordpress.com. Any links to tutorials would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jetpack will allow you to authorize applications and services to securely connect to your blog and allow them to use your content in new ways and offer you new functionality.

Developers can use WordPress.com’s [OAuth2](http://developer.wordpress.com/docs/oauth2/) authentication system and WordPress.com [REST API](http://developer.wordpress.com/docs/api/) to manage and access your site’s content.

You can also learn more about the API by visiting the [REST API documentation](http://developer.wordpress.com/docs/api/).